# C# partner wsdl binding.QueryOptionsValue.batchSize not being set

Tags: c#, wsdl, .net, partner-wsdl

So I have a C# program that does an automated backup of all custom objects in are org in the login method which I have posted below I set the querybatch size

```
    private bool login()
    {
        try
        {
            binding = new SforceService();
            binding.Timeout = 180000;
            lr = binding.login("username", "password+token");
            binding.Url = lr.serverUrl;
            binding.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader { sessionId = lr.sessionId };
            binding.QueryOptionsValue = new SforceBackup.QueryOptions();
            binding.QueryOptionsValue.batchSize = 50;
            binding.QueryOptionsValue.batchSizeSpecified = true;
            return true;
        }
        catch (SoapException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            using (StreamWriter writer =
             new StreamWriter("somefile", true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Later in my code i build an sqlbody and query it with the following line

QueryResult qr = binding.queryAll("Select " + sqlbody + "From " + objectname + " where isdeleted=false");

But when I set the Sobject array to sObject[] records = qr.records; it alway returns 200 records

****Note the whole program runs to completion but occasionally times out with some larger objects (800 fields) in are org on this line ***

qr = binding.queryMore(qr.queryLocator);

So I figure if I can set the batchsize it should take care of the problem but no matter where I set it in the program I get 200 records return(I checked the stack with a breakpoint and its being set there).

**Note not interested in Salesforce weekly backup or anything on the appexchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you cannot go lower than 200 as per **[QueryOptions documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_header_queryoptions.htm):**

> The default is 500; **the minimum is 200**, and the maximum is 2,000. There is no guarantee that the requested batch size will be the actual batch size; this is done to maximize performance.

Comment: Thanks some much pnoytechie didn't see that in the documentation. What I had to do is handle the larger objects in a separate function using and id in query that a generated and when that function is finished log out because on concurrent api request then log back in and run the rest of the objects